# fs.mkdirSync() make directory in remote server folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, mkdir

In Node.js, I'm attempting to use fs.mkdirSync() to create a new directory in a remote server/folder structure '\\myserver.com'

My computer (Windows) seems to be connected to this server, have permissions to access it, and is viewable and editable in my File Explorer. fs.mkdirSync() seems to have no issue creating folders locally on my machine, but when I put the server path as the directory, it throws an error

Code:

```
fs.mkdirSync("\\\\myserver.com\\folder1\\folder2\\new folder")
```

Error:

```
{ Error: EPROTO: protocol error, mkdir '\\myserver.com\folder1\folder2\new folder'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at exports.create_new_folder (/file_calling_mkDir.js:107:6)
  errno: -71,
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '\\myserver.com\folder1\folder2\new folder' }
```

What seems to be going wrong here? The folder does not get created and there isn't much documentation on using fs with server paths for me to refer to, making this difficult to solve. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to include the OS of your local machine and the server. I'm guessing both Windows/Windows shares based on the syntax?

Comment: @Slbox Yes both are Windows based. Every machine that will be using these files will be Windows oriented as well